# Check next record exists in database

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I am using Zend `fetch` method to fetch huge number of records from database for creating reports.Since `fetchAll` is costly as compared to fetch i am using it.And if its the last row i need to add some additinoal logic.So my question is that is there a way to check if next record exists or not inside the while loop. I am using it like the following

```
//$select is the select query
$objDb      = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$objAchQry = $objDb->query($select);
while($arrResult = $objAchQry->fetch()) {
  //Do something

  //I need to do something here if its the last record like
  /*
  if($last_rec)
    do something
  */
}
```

Is there a way to check if the current one is last record or if any other record exists. I know to do it by taking count of records and incrementing a counter inside the loop.But i dont need it.Any solutions.?

Comment: "is there a way to check if next record exists" The condition on your while loop does exactly just that. The loop won't execute any more if no more rows exist to fetch.

Comment: one way, you can have a counter in the loop, and in the beggining total no of records. If counter < total then you have next record else you are on last record.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp so i want to check the current one is last one or not inside while. i know it will stop execution if no more rows are there.But how will i know that current one is the last record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is there a way to check if next record exists" The condition on your while loop does exactly just that. The loop won't execute any more if no more rows exist to fetch.

Think of it this way:

```
while($arrResult = $objAchQry->fetch()) {

  //Do something

}

// Now I'm just after the last record
/*
do something
*/
```

If you *really* need to do something *before* the last row is processed, you could modify your code to

```
$total_records = // get total no of rows
$counter = 0;
while($arrResult = $objAchQry->current()) {
  //Do something
  $counter ++;

  //I need to do something here if its the last record like

  if( ! $bojAchQry->next()) {

    // The row currently being processed is the last one.

  } else {

    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to go after the last record.I need it when it is the last record.

Comment: I dont think there is a method named `current and next` in pdo.

Answer (score 1):

One way - You can track with counter,

```
$total_records = // get total no of rows
$counter = 0;
while($arrResult = $objAchQry->fetch()) {
  //Do something
  $counter ++;

  //I need to do something here if its the last record like

  if($counter == $total_records  ) // this iteration will be the last one.
   //do something

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i have mentioned in the question that i dont want to do the logic with a counter.

Comment: @Deepu: you welcome, but sometimes we are bound to use the existing provided functions, and we use those functions for our problem. Similarly I do't think there is a any function in php mysql connection library that provides at a time the next row and previous  row iterations.